# jquery - simple accordion

Tags: jquery

Its a simple Accordion, this is what I want [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tq5Y8/) but i need to edit the HTML code to pass the validation. And I don't know how to customize the jquery. my sample code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/8kp3D/)

Origal code:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Sports</li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
    </ul>
<li>Latest</li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

to this code:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Sports
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li>Latest
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
        </ul> 
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` i need to edit the HTML code to pass the validation. `?

Comment: what is the validation that you are going to do?

Comment: you have not put the close </li> tag of "Latest" in your last code

Comment: what changes you want affect to the original source codes ?

Comment: @Icarus i mean sir to pass W3C validator.

Comment: I ran the W3C validator on the iframe containing the results of your jsfiddle, and it passed. What's the problem?

Comment: all of you. Thank you for giving time to my question I found the answer here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your javascript from the jsfiddle to this:

```
$("#accordion > li").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
    if(false == $(this).find('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(300);
});

var animationIsOff = $.fx.off;
$.fx.off = true;
$('#accordion > li:eq(0)').click()
$.fx.off = animationIsOff;
```

Comment: I have concert sir i need also is when i click the tab again it will back to normal color again

Comment: Move the line `$(this).addClass('active');` into the if statement

Comment: hi sir there steel one problem when i click another tab the open tab should close